Change of base is a closed immersion
I've read about closed immersions being stable under base changes, but I have the following question.
Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of $S$-schemes such that $f$ is an immersion and assume furthermore that $f$ is proper. Can we conclude that the base change $\operatorname{Id} \times_S f: X \times_S X \to X \times_S Y$ is a closed immersion?
I already know it should be an immersion since these are stable under base changes, but can we lift "immersion" to "closed immersion" using the fact that $f$ is proper?
Thanks in advance!

Sure, but for easier reasons than you may be expecting - a proper map has closed image, so in particular, a proper immersion is an immersion with closed image, which is a closed immersion. So $f$ is a closed immersion and therefore since closed immersions are stable under base change, $Id\times_S f$ is a closed immersion. If this resolves your question, I think it should be a duplicate of that linked post - what do you think?

@KReiser Yes that does help a lot actually! I never thought about a proper morphism having closed image since it only talks about the closedness of projection. But now that I think of it, we have that $Y \times_X X \cong Y$ are isomorphic, right? By the uniqueness up to unique isomorphism of the fibered product?

Yes, exactly - all pullbacks are closed maps implies that the original is a closed map if you pull back along the identity $Y\to Y$.
